# @Injectable giving undefined in angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, dependencies

Hello guys I've recently updated angular to the version 13 and I'm experiencing some issues regarding DI. When I call the `ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate()` function it gives me undefined error. What may be the possible reason behind this one guys, do you maybe know ?
I'm having problems with `ScheduleProvider` which is decorated by `@Injectable()` and injected inside my `pro-container.js` file.

Here are the connected parts:

*schedule-provider.js*

```
import { Injectable } from 'injection-js';

import { MzpackgHttpService, MzpackgLightResource, MzpackgListFilter } from 'mzpackg-api-schedules';

@Injectable()
export class ScheduleProvider {
public schedule= {
/*
  some data
*/
};

public constructor(private readonly mzPackgHttpService: MzpackgHttpService) {}
}
```

*pro-container.js*

```
import { InjectionToken, Provider, ReflectiveInjector } from 'injection-js';

import {
 RolesPartiesHttpService,
 HttpService,
} from 'mzpackg-api-roles';

import {PaymentsHttpService } from 'mzpackg-api-payments';
import { LawHttpService } from 'mzpackg-api-law';
import {
TasksHttpService,
} from 'mzpackg-api-tasks';
import { BrokersHttpService } from 'mzpackg-api-brokers';
import {
 HttpService as ExtendedPaymentHttpService
} from 'mzpackg-api-extpayments';

import { ScheduleProvider } from './schedule-provider';

export const BROKERS_HTTP_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<HttpService>('broker http service');
export const PAYMENTS_HTTP_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<ExtendedPaymentHttpService>('payments http service');

export class ProContainer{
  private readonly providers: Provider[];

  public constructor() {
    this.providers = [
      {
        provide: BrokersHttpService,
        useFactory: (httpService: HttpService) => new BrokersHttpService(httpService),
        deps: [BROKERS_HTTP_SERVICE]
      },      
      {
        provide: PaymentsHttpService,
        useFactory: (httpService: HttpService) => new PaymentsHttpService(httpService),
        deps: [PAYMENTS_HTTP_SERVICE]
      },
       {
        provide: ScheduleProvider,
        useFactory: (tasksHttpService: TasksHttpService) => new 
ScheduleProvider(tasksHttpService),
        deps: [TasksHttpService, RolesPartiesHttpService, LawHttpService]
       },
    ];
  }

}
```

The problem is when I comment `ScheduleProvider` it works, so `ScheduleProvider` is giving me `undefined` error. My angular packages versions are :

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1302.6

@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.2.6

@angular-devkit/core            13.2.6

@angular-devkit/schematics      13.2.6

@angular/cdk                    13.2.6

@angular/cli                    13.2.6

@angular/compiler-cli           13.2.6

@angular/language-service       13.2.6

@angular/material               13.2.6

@schematics/angular             13.2.6

rxjs                            6.6.7

typescript                      4.5.5
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what's the reason you are using `injection-js` and not just `@angular/core`?

Comment: there was fesm2015 dynamic import() error for @angular/core if I wanted to import Injectors from it

Comment: that's weird, you should probably just remove your node_modules and try again using `npm i`

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/ReflectiveInjector - ReflectiveInjector is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The [official docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ReflectiveInjector#description) days:

> Deprecated: from v5 - slow and brings in a lot of code, Use `Injector.create` instead.

Usage (from [official docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector)):

```
const injector: Injector =
    Injector.create({providers: [{provide: 'validToken', useValue: 'Value'}]});
expect(injector.get('validToken')).toEqual('Value');
expect(() => injector.get('invalidToken')).toThrowError();
expect(injector.get('invalidToken', 'notFound')).toEqual('notFound');
```

Injector returns itself when given Injector as a token:

```
const injector = Injector.create({providers: []});
expect(injector.get(Injector)).toBe(injector);
```